# Is there a problem with a4j:commandButtons that get 'reRendered'?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

The code below has been simplified to the simplest possible thing that is failing. Basically when someone requests to confirm an action, I am forcing them to login, then allowing them to confirm the action. This is all done with ajax. The first form submission happens correctly but the second one fails to run the desired ActionListener. The second form is posting to the server though.

```
<h:panelGroup id="confirmPanelWrapper">
    <h:panelGroup id="loginPanelInner" rendered="#{(!login.authenticated)}">
        <a4j:form id="loginForm">
            <h:outputText value="Enter your proctor login."/><br/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="User Name *"/><br/>
            <h:inputText size="30" id="username" value="#{login.username}"/><br/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="Password *"/><br/>
            <h:inputSecret size="30" id="password" value="#{login.password}"/><br/>
            <br/>
            <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{login.authenticateProctor}" reRender="confirmPanelWrapper"/>
        </a4j:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="confirmPanel" rendered="#{(login.authenticated)}">
        <a4j:form id="confirmForm">
            <a4j:commandButton
                       value="Yes"
                       id="confirmTest"
                       actionListener="#{beanName.confirmTestAssociation}"
                       reRender="confirmPanelWrapper"
                       style="padding-right:10px;"/>
            <a4j:commandButton
                       value="No"
                       id="denyTest"
                       reRender="confirmPanelWrapper"
                       actionListener="#{beanName.selectionNotConfirmed}"/>
        </a4j:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the server log?

Comment: No, the server log says nonthing at all. There is even a log message in joinTestSession.confirmTestAssociation that should be printed when that method is called, but it never is.

Comment: What is the scope of the "login" artefact? Check the state of #{login.authenticated} when the confirmation action occurs. If it evaluates to false, the button decode will not happen.

Comment: That was it. Login was request scoped. Made that change and it all worked correctly.